# Не могу установить БД из-за ошибки: [INS-35180] Unable to check for available memory

Tags: java, oracle, oracle19c

В общем с установкой вначале все в порядке, но когда открывается данная часть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

выводится ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: вы показываете четверть сообщения об ошибке.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка при установке БД в Ubuntu 16.04: \[INS-35180\] Unable to check for available memory](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1181889/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%91%d0%94-%d0%b2-ubuntu-16-04-ins-35180-unable-to-check-for-availabl)