# Ошибка при установке БД в Ubuntu 16.04: [INS-35180] Unable to check for available memory

Tags: база-данных, oracle, install, oracle19c

При установке в Ubuntu 16.04 Oracle БД 19c выдает такую  ошибку:

```
[INS-35180] Unable to check for available memory
```

---

```
Additional Information:
Exception details  - PRVG-1901 : failed to setup CVU remote execution framework directory "/tmp/InstallActions2020-09-24_04-50-55AM/CVU_19.0.0.0.0_ubuntu/" on nodes "ubuntu-psb133s01zfh"
Please select a different work area for the framework
An internal error occurred within cluster verification framework
The command executed was "/tmp/InstallActions2020-09-24_04-50-55AM/CVU_19.0.0.0.0_ubuntu//exectask.sh -getver". The output from the command was "/tmp/InstallActions2020-09-24_04-50-55AM/CVU_19.0.0.0.0_ubuntu/exectask: error while loading shared libraries: libaio.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

An internal error occurred within cluster verification framework
The command executed was "/tmp/InstallActions2020-09-24_04-50-55AM/CVU_19.0.0.0.0_ubuntu//exectask.sh -getver". The output from the command was "/tmp/InstallActions2020-09-24_04-50-55AM/CVU_19.0.0.0.0_ubuntu/exectask: error while loading shared libraries: libaio.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"
Version of exectask could not be retrieved from node "ubuntu-psb133s01zfh"
```

Comment: Поясните что вам непонятно в данных сообщениях?

Comment: [INS-35180] Unable to check for available memory.

Comment: Всегда приводите в вопросе команды, которые вы использовали.

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

DBCA не в состоянии проверить объем доступной памяти в системе.

Чтобы обойти ошибку, запустите DBCA вручную и добавьте следующий параметр:

```
dbca -J-Doracle.assistants.dbca.validate.ConfigurationParams=false &
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55168409) участника [@0xdb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6571020/0xdb) на вопрос:

[Getting “Unable to check for available memory.” on Oracle DB 18c](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55019218)</sub>